# Sigmoid function as result of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When plugging the differential equation $\frac{dP}{dt}=P(1-P)$ into a symbolab differential equation calculator I get the result $- \frac{e^{t + c_1}}{1 - e^{t+c_1}}$. I don't know if this is correct because the correct solution in the book should be a sigmoid function $\frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}$. Is the calculator solution correct?

Comment: Is there any initial conditions to the DE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. If $P(t)=-\frac{e^{t+c}}{1-e^{t+c}}$, then$$P'(t)=-\frac{e^{t+c}}{\left(e^{t+c}-1\right)^2},$$whereas$$P(t)\bigl(1-P(t)\bigr)=-\frac{e^{t+c}}{1-e^{t+c}}\times\frac1{1-e^{t+c}}=-\frac{e^{t+c}}{\left(e^{t+c}-1\right)^2}.$$So, yes, those functions are solutions of your differential equation.

Comment: Can $- \frac{e^{t + c_1}}{1 - e^{t+c_1}}$ be rewritten as $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$?

Comment: @MichaelMunta You can't you have a constant here and not there

Comment: There is no $c$ for which $\frac1{1+e^{-x}}=-\frac{e^{x+c}}{1-e^{x+c}}$, because $\frac1{1+e^{-x}}$ is defined everywhere, whereas $-\frac{e^{x+c}}{1-e^{x+c}}$ has an asymptote at $x=-c$.

Comment: Just to clarify $\frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}$ is a solution as well?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've checked it.

Comment: So what is the difference between these two solutions? If they can't be rewritten with a specific constant?

Comment: There are *two* families of solutions: $\frac1{1-e^{-t+c}}$ (this is the one you got from Symbolab) and $\frac1{1+e^{t+c}}$. Besides these ones, the constant functions $0$ and $1$ are also solutions.

Comment: Would you be willing to edit your answer with solution process for how to get the two different solutions? I want to see where does the process of solving DE differ for the two solutions.

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

This solution form is incomplete. Somewhere along the way there was only one case in the resolution of an absolute value considered. The more general result uses $C=\pm e^{c_1}$ to get
$$
y(x)=\frac{Ce^t}{1+Ce^t}=\frac1{1/C+e^{-t}}.
$$

---

The probable calculation is
$$
dt=\frac{dP}P+\frac{dP}{1-P}\implies t+c_1=\ln|P|-\ln|P-1|
\\~\\
e^{t+c_1}=\left|\frac{P}{P-1}\right|\implies \pm e^{t+c_1}=1-\frac1{1-P}
$$
where clearly you get solutions with both signs in $C$ and also for $C=0$ and formally for $C=\infty$.