# Process of solving a differential equation with different solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to see where does the process of solving a differential equation $$\frac{dP}{dt} = P(1-P)$$ differ for the two solutions $- \frac{e^{t + c_1}}{1 - e^{t+c_1}}$ and $\frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}.$ This is related to my other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609587/sigmoid-function-as-result-of-differential-equation/).

Comment: What do you mean by  "it differs" ?

Comment: Without a constant factor the solutions cannot be the same. At the second solution the constant factor is missing.

Comment: @callculus True the second solution is a particular solution with a certain initial condition

Comment: @Aryadeva But this has to be clarified by the OP. The information are incomplete.

Comment: Yes I know. Maybe in the book there is an initial condition.

Comment: To summarize: What is the initial condition, Michael?

Comment: There is no initial condition. The book literally says to show that the solution to this DE is a sigmoid function.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = P(1-P)$$
$$P'-P = -P^2$$
I assume $P \ne 0$:
$$\frac{P'}{P^2}-\dfrac 1 P = -1$$
$$\left (\frac{1}{P} \right )'+\dfrac 1 P = 1$$
Substitute $u=\dfrac 1 P$ you get $u'+u = 1$ that you can rewrite as :$ (ue^t)'=e^t$. Integrate you get
$u(t)=1+ce^{-t}$.
Therefore:
$$\boxed {P(t)=\dfrac 1 {1+ce^{-t}}}$$
To get the Sigmoid Function of your book you need some specific inital condition. So that  $\implies c=1$

Comment: You substituted $k = -e^{c_1}$ which means that $k < 0$.  Hence, how you take $k = 1$? It cannot be true.

Comment: You are right. Corrected... Thanks  @AnastassisKapetanakis

Comment: @Aryadeva If the equation is simply telling us that the derivative is $P(1 - P)$, can't we just use the indefinite integral on this to find solution? I am new at this, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Nope you can't it's a Bernouilli equation @MichaelMunta

Comment: Thank you, can you maybe check my other question from today?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612135/rewriting-logistic-function-into-standard-form

Comment: You're welcome @MichaelMunta Sure will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

By separation of variabels we get(Assuming $P \ne 0 \space and \space P \ne 1$):

$$ \frac{1}{P(1-P)}dP = dt \implies$$
$$ (\frac{1}{P}+\frac{1}{1 - P})dP = dt \implies$$
$$ln|P| - ln|1 - P| = t + c_1 \implies$$
$$|\frac{P}{1-P}| = e^{t+c_1}$$

Now you must find a way to get rid of the absolute values amd that depends on the initial value. Because $|\frac{P}{1-P}| = e^{t+c_1} \ne 0$ and $|\frac{P}{1-P}|$ continuous we have that:

1. If $\frac{P(t_0)}{1-P(t_0)} > 0$ we have as a solution $\frac{1}{1+e^{t+c_1}}$
2. If $\frac{P(t_0)}{1-P(t_0)} < 0$ we have as a solution $-\frac{e^{t+c_1}}{1-e^{t+c_1}}$
3. If $\frac{P(t_0)}{1-P(t_0)} = 0$ you must have another information.

Caution: We excluded from the beginning $P = 0 \space and \space P = 1$. As you see they too are solutions to the ODE.