# Rewriting logistic function into standard form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My book defines the standard form of a logistic function as $f(x) = A \cdot \frac{1 + B \cdot e^{-\frac{x}{a}}}{1 + C \cdot e^{-\frac{x}{a}}}$, while [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) defines it as $f(x) = \frac{L}{1 + e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$. Can anyone show how to rewrite this logistic function into both of these standard forms $$P(t) = \frac{K \cdot P_0 \cdot e^{r\cdot t}}{K + P_0 \cdot (e^{r \cdot t}-1)}$$?

Comment: It's a textbook for financial mathematics in my native language.

Comment: Croatian. I doubt it would help you, I gave all the information I could from the book.

Comment: Ok Michael Thanks

Comment: Can you answer with the information that is provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first form ...

$$\begin{align}
P(t) &= K\cdot \frac{P_0e^{rt}}{K + P_0 \cdot (e^{rt}-1)} \tag{1}\\[4pt]
&= K\cdot\frac{P_0e^{rt}+ 0}{P_0 e^{rt}+(K-P_0)}\cdot\frac{1/(P_0e^{rt})}{1/(P_0e^{rt})} \tag{2}\\[4pt]
&= K\cdot\frac{1+ 0e^{-rt}}{1+\frac{K-P_0}{P_0}e^{-rt}} \tag{3}\\[4pt]
&= K\cdot \frac{1+Be^{-t/a}}{1+Ce^{-t/a}} \qquad B:=0, C:=\frac{K-P_0}{P_0}, a := \frac1r \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

For the second form, starting from $(3)$ above ...

$$\begin{align}
P(t) &= \frac{K}{1 + \frac{K-P_0}{P_0}e^{-rt}} \tag{5}\\[4pt]
&= \frac{K}{1 + e^se^{-rt}} \qquad s := \log\frac{K-P_0}{P_0} \tag{6}\\[4pt]
&= \frac{K}{1 + e^{-r(t-t_0)}} \qquad t_0 := \frac{s}{r} = \frac1r\log\frac{K-P_0}{P_0} \tag{7}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Blue Can you please also add how to go from $(2)$ to $(3)$?

Comment: @MichaelMunta: Dividing the numerator by $P_0 e^{rt}$, the $P_0 e^{rt}$ becomes $1$, and the $0$ becomes ... well, $0$ ... but to make it match the form you're after, I wrote it as $0\cdot e^{-rt}$. Dividing the denominator by $P_0e^{rt}$, the $P_0 e^{rt}$ becomes $1$ as before, and $K-P_0$ becomes $$\frac{K-P_0}{P_0 e^{rt}} \quad\to\quad \frac{K-P_0}{P_0}\cdot\frac{1}{e^{rt}}\quad\to\quad \frac{K-P_0}{P_0}e^{-rt}$$ Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I was confused with the $0e^{-rt}$. So as long as we know that the expression evaluates to $0$ we can write anything we want as a factor with $0$?

Comment: @MichaelMunta: Yes. $0\cdot a=0$ for all real $a$. One typically reads that equation from left-to-right —"the product of zero and anything is zero"— but one can *cleverly* read right-to-left —"zero is the product of zero and anything"— when wrestling an expression into a desired form. The same kind of idea explains going from $(1)$ to $(2)$; as $a+0=a$ for any $a$, I can write any $a$ as $a+0$ whenever it suits me. Likewise, with that multiplied fraction in $(2)$, since $\frac{a}{a}=1$ for any (non-zero) $a$, I can expand $1$ as $\frac{a}{a}$ for any (non-zero) $a$ I like; eg, $1/(P_0e^{rt})$.

Comment: @MichaelMunta: By the way, generally speaking, you should wait until the bounty period is over before awarding it. Awarding a bounty early is inconsiderate to those who may be off working on absolutely *brilliant* answers, thinking they have the full week to polish them before posting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Though I just wanted to see if it is possible since believe it or not a professor I contacted with this said that it could not be done.

Comment: @MichaelMunta You can award bounties right away. Nobody thinks they have the full week to "polish" answers; everyone understands that there is somewhat of a rush to post the answer first.

Comment: @Blue "Awarding a bounty early is inconsiderate to those who may be off working on absolutely brilliant answers, thinking they have the full week to polish them before posting." With all due respect, this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

As it follows from the wikipedia link, the standard logistic function is
$$f(x) = \dfrac1{1+e^{-x}} = \dfrac{e^x}{e^x+1}.\tag1$$

At the same time, any other function can be considered as the generalized logistic function, if can be shown parameters, which transforms it to the form $(1).$

In the first case, these parameters are $A=1,\ B=0,\ C=1,\ a=1.$

In the second case, as it is shown in the link, $k=1,\ x^\,_0 = 0,\ L=1.$

In the third case, $K=1,\ P_0 = \dfrac12.$

Therefore, all functions from OP are the different generalizations of the basic function $(1).$