# Logistic function requirement of Euler's constant

Tags: functions

I am wondering if Euler's constant is a requirement for a certain function to be called logistic. Take for example this logistic function from wikipedia $$f(x) = \frac{L}{1 + e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$$

Say we replaced Euler's constant with some arbitrary real number, would we still call this function logistic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e$ is replaced with another number $a$, we can always rewrite the expression back into a form with $e$, for $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$. Thus the variable $k$ becomes $k\ln a$ and it is still logistic.

Comment: So how would one differentiate the logistic function from for example an exponential function? Only by its graph?

Comment: @MichaelMunta The logistic function is sigmoid shape. The exponential function is just a convex curve.

Comment: So as long as a function has a characteristic that for infinitely large $x$ it tends to the upper asymptote we can classify it as logistic function?

Comment: @MichaelMunta No. A logistic function has to be of the type you presented in the question body.

Comment: Ok, could you maybe check out my other question that is still unanswered. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612135/rewriting-logistic-function-into-standard-form?noredirect=1#comment7425684_3612135

Comment: Since you say that it has to be in this form I wonder if it can then be rewritten.